# Update output displayed json data when changing select value dropdown

Tags: javascript

I basically want to dynamically update the displayed output json fields based on what value I select in a dropdown, without reloading the page. In this case, display the city based on the selected AveragePrice dropdown. By the way, it's plain javascript (Vanilla)

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "country":"UK",
      "cities":[
         {
            "city":"Manchester",
            "averagePrice":100
         },
         {
            "city":"London",
            "averagePrice":300
         },
      ]
   },
  {
      "country":"France",
      "cities":[
         {
            "city":"Toulouse",
            "averagePrice":150
         },
         {
            "city":"Nice",
            "averagePrice":200
         },
      ]
   },
]
```

HTML:

```
<div id="city"></div>
<select id="averagePriceDropdown">
 <option value="100">100</option>
 <option value="150">150</option>
 <option value="175">175</option>
 <option value="200">200</option>
 <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var valueDropdown = document.getElementById("averagePriceDropdown");
var valueData = valueDropdown.options[valueDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

var getAverage = async function () {
    fetch("../data/data.json").then(
        res => {
            res.json().then(
                data => {
                    for (var x in data) {
                        if (data[x].cities[x].averagePrice == valueData) {
                            return document.getElementById("city").innerHTML += data[x].cities[x].city;
                        } else {
                            return document.getElementById("city").innerHTML += "Could not find city.";
                        }
                    }


                }
            )
        }
    )

};
```

As you can see, I'm defining variable names for different ID fields. In the IF condition, I am updating the city text content (innerHTML) matching the AveragePrice. It works if I change the default dropdown value in the HTML and reload the page, it renders the correct city. But changing the dropdown on the page, it doesn't update the city. I tried adding an onchange eventlistener to the dropdown but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not referencing the array elements correctly.  Here is how you want to cycle through the data and make the comparison:

```js
function choose(){
    var valueDropdown = document.getElementById("averagePriceDropdown");
    var valueData = valueDropdown.options[valueDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    var i, j, match;
    match = false;
    for (i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < data[i].cities.length; j++){
            if (data[i].cities[j].averagePrice == valueData){
                match = true;
                console.log("Matching cities: " + data[i].cities[j].city);
                document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = data[i].cities[j].city
            }
        }
    }
    if (match == false) {
        console.log("No matching cities for average price = " + valueData);
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "No matching cities.";
    }

}
    
data = 
    [
       {
          "country":"UK",
          "cities":[
             {
                "city":"Manchester",
                "averagePrice":100
             },
             {
                "city":"London",
                "averagePrice":300
             },
          ]
       },
      {
          "country":"France",
          "cities":[
             {
                "city":"Toulouse",
                "averagePrice":150
             },
             {
                "city":"Nice",
                "averagePrice":200
             },
          ]
       },
    ]
```

```html
<div id="city"></div>
<select id="averagePriceDropdown" onchange="choose()">
 <option value="-">-</option>
 <option value="100">100</option>
 <option value="150">150</option>
 <option value="175">175</option>
 <option value="200">200</option>
 <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks @crosen9999.

So everything needs to be in the onchange function (choose()) to be able to update the results. Also I'm not going to use innerHTML, but textContent instead.

Many thanks!